# Funcion para concatenar datos de tabla html y jquery

Tags: javascript, html

**tengo una table en html con un checkbox en cada row lo que necesito es que que al seleccionar el checkbox me tome el valor de una celda**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Seleccionar</th>
        <th>ejemplo</th>
        <th>ehemplo</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="guardadatos();"></td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="guardadatos();"></td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**y la siguiente función si me toma el valor de la celda pero al seleccionar el otro checkbox me los concatena y me repite el valor mostrandome un "undefined" cada vez que se repito el each**

```
function guardadatos() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        id = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(1).html();
        texto += id;
        texto +="<br/>";
      });
}
```

Comment: Lo que vos queres obtener son todos los valores concatenados? no entiendo bien!

Comment: necesito seleccionar un valor del row de la tabla pero al seleccionar otro checkbox necesito que se concatenen los dos valores,  ir formando un texto cada que se selecciona un checkbox con los valores que hay dentro del <td>

Comment: Pero necesitas todos los valores de cada td de cada fila tildada? o uno en específico?

Comment: es uno en especifico por eso utilizo `eq(1) `

Comment: si los concatena bien, el problema es que si yo selecciono 5 renglones se repite el texto 5 veces y yo necesito que se muestre el texto solo una vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que inicializar la variable texto dentro de la funcion.  Algo asi:

```js
function guardadatos() {
    var texto = '';
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        id = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(1).html();
        texto += id;
        texto +="<br/>";        
      });
      console.log(texto);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Seleccionar</th>
        <th>ejemplo</th>
        <th>ehemplo</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="guardadatos();"></td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="guardadatos();"></td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
            <td>ejemplo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: la variable texto  ya la inicializo antes para tomarla como variable global, el problema que tengo es que cuando elijo muchos checkbox por ejemplo 5 y muestro la variable texto en textarea, me repite 5 veces lo mismo, no sé si lo estoy haciendo incorrectamente pero cada vez que me muestra los archivos me sale un 'undefined'

Comment: Si es una variable global, simplemente remueve el var de mi codigo.

Comment: Tienes razón, una consulta más como evito que me ponga el 'undefined' al principio del texto?

Comment: No se porque te sale `undefined`.  Prueba inicializando la variable con una cadena vacia como en mi respuesta.

Comment: lo dejé tal cual tu respuesta solo quité el 'var'.

Comment: Me refiero a donde primero declaras la variable.

Comment: cierto xD gracias